# Make controls of multiple objects visible

Tags: fabricjs

I try to implement a rotation around a movable rotation point:
I got so far:

`here's some snipped`
https://jsfiddle.net/Lwg6fkhs/60/

In the example you can select the blue rotation point and the red rect will rotate around that point. You can also move the rotation point somewhere else and the rect will continue rotating around that point.

At the moment the resize controls are only visible if the red rectangle is focused or the rotate control is visible when the rotation point is focused. I would like to make all controls (grab handles) of the red rectangle and the rotation rectangle visible at the same time.  Is that possible? Or is there another way to implement that behavior with less or similar amount of code by modifying the behavior of the red rectangles rotation control?